# Phpstorm : Make "fuzzy opening" ignore specific characters

Tags: sublimetext2, phpstorm

I'm looking for the way to make PhpStorm use the same fuzzy opening behaviour as SublimeText.

Example : the file i want to access is :

```
/admin/controller/user/user_controller.php
```

In sublime text i'll open i can open it with :

```
admctrlusrctrl
```

But in PhpStorm i've got to add slashes  and can't write per example "usr" for "user_controller"

Any way to fix that ?

Thanks ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not currently possible, please vote for [IDEABKL-6959](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-6959).

see https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/navigating-to-class-file-or-symbol-by-name.html for some tips on using Navigate/File

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately PhpStorm don't accept `admctrlusrctrl` format.

Corrected will be `ucon` or `admin/ucon` because PhpStorm consider slashes as delimiter.